# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chefsBackEnd.wsgi' Django RF API Deploying with Heroku and Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I am attempting to deploy my api to heroku. The api uses PIPENV as the virutal env; Django Rest Framework. When I deploy to heroku, I get the following logs: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chefsBackEnd.wsgi'.

After doing some research, I found that the name of application goes before .wsgi. The information showed to set up in Procfile writing exactly: web: gunicorn chefsBackEnd.wsgi --log-file -

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn chefsBackEnd.wsgi --log-level=info --log-file -
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
manage.py migrate
```

wsgi.py:

```
import os
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'chefsBackEnd.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Here is my settings.py for django:

```
import os
import django_heroku

# import cloudinary

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'p%s-9w1l268@!b$p#92dj26q)pv7!&ln^3m(1j5#!k8pkc9@(u'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mock-chefs-table-api.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    # 'allauth',
    # 'allauth.account',
    # 'allauth.socialaccount',
    'corsheaders',
    # 'pyuploadcare.dj',
    # 'cloudinary',
    # 'rest_auth',
    # 'rest_auth.registration',
    'rest_framework',
    # 'rest_framework.authtoken',

    'menus',
    # 'phlogfeeder',
    'login',
    # 'posts',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'chefsBackEnd.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

> **Here is my WSGI**

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'chefsBackEnd.wsgi.application'




DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator'},
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator'},
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator'},
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator'},
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


# MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media').replace('\\', '/')


SITE_ID = 1

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',

        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
    
}

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True


CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://localhost:5000',

    'https://chefs-table-mock-site.herokuapp.com',
    # 'https://git.heroku.com/phlog-api.git'

]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'chefsBackEnd.utils.resp_handler',
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'JWT_VERIFY': True,
}

CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "csrftoken"

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Here are the heroku tail --logs:

- self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi() File
  "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py",
  line 67, in wsgi      self.callable = self.load() File
  "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
  line 49, in load   return self.load_wsgiapp()  File
  "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
  line 39, in load_wsgiapp  return util.import_app(self.app_uri)  File
  "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py",
  line 358, in import_app   mod = importlib.import_module(module) File
  "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/**init**.py", line 127,
  in import_module          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:],
  package, level) File "", line 1014, in
  _gcd_import File "", line 991, in _find_and_load

  File "", line 973, in
  _find_and_load_unlocked
  **2020-07-04T14:22:54.643634+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chefsBackEnd.wsgi'** [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
  [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to
  boot.

Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]
pylint = "*"

[packages]
django-rest-framework = "==0.1.0"
django-cors-headers = "==3.2.1"
django-rest-auth = {extras = ["with-social"],version = "==0.9.5"}
pusher = "==3.0.0"
django-allauth = "==0.41.0"
djangorestframework-simplejwt = "==4.4.0"
djangorestframework-jwt = "==1.11.0"
pyuploadcare = "==2.7.0"
cloudinary = "==1.20.0"
gunicorn = "*"
django-heroku = "*"
asgiref = "==3.2.7"
certifi = "==2020.4.5.1"
cffi = "==1.14.0"
chardet = "==3.0.4"
cryptography = "==2.9.2"
defusedxml = "==0.6.0"
djangorestframework = "==3.11.0"
idna = "==2.9"
ndg-httpsclient = "==0.5.1"
oauthlib = "==3.1.0"
pyasn1 = "==0.4.8"
pycparser = "==2.20"
python-dateutil = "==2.8.1"
python3-openid = "==3.1.0"
pytz = "==2020.1"
requests-oauthlib = "==1.3.0"
requests = "==2.23.0"
six = "==1.14.0"
sqlparse = "==0.3.1"
urllib3 = "==1.25.9"
Django = "==3.0.6"
Pillow = "==7.1.2"
PyJWT = "==1.7.1"
PyNaCl = "==1.3.0"
pyOpenSSL = "==19.1.0"
whitenoise = "*"
dependency = "*"
python-dotenv = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```